# Determine the Degree to Which Elements of Two Lists are Grouped

Tags: python, algorithm

What I would like to do is determine the degree to which common elements of two strings are grouped.  There may be a mathematical function, or scipy/numpy/etc function already to do this.  I just do not know what it is called.  And I have googled for it.  For example:

This set would have a perfect score (all like elements are grouped):

```
['a','a','a','b','b','b']
```

So would:

```
['b','b','b','a','a','a']
```

This series would have a lessor score:

```
['a','a','b','b','b','a']
```

And this series would have a very low score:

```
['a','b','a','b','a','b']
```

I can think of several ways to implement this, I am just wondering if there is already a function/algorithm for this sort of thing defined.

I thought of perhaps generating a perfectly grouped string, based on the counts of the discrete values in the stings and calculating the Levenshtein distance between the actual string and perfect one.  For example, compare:

```
['a','a','a','b','b','b']
```

to:

```
['b','b','b','a','a','a']
```

But again, I am looking for if this algorithm has a name and implementation already.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think of any existing metrics for this but it seems easy to make up one. What you're asking is to count the number of groups in the array.

My metric: length of array divided by number of groups

Definition:

```
def metric(lst):
    L = len(lst)
    n = len(list(itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x: x)))
    return L/float(n)   # you can omit float if python 3
```

The `groupby` will count how may blocks of identical elements in the array `lst`. You do not want to sort it as you would normally do with `groupby` because you are counting for *changes* in element of `lst`. Then we take length of `lst` divided by the number of blocks to find the "mean block length". This should fit your requirement.

You may need to gauge the metric. In the case above, it will favor longer arrays with fewer blocks. You may consider square root of `L`, for example, to make the metric follow *law of diminishing return*.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [adrtam's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9214517/adrtam) answer. I have made a few modifications to it:

1. Improved completeness and made it work when I run it
2. Made the metric independent of the size of the list
3. Changed the metric so that a perfectly grouped list will have a score of 1 (the lowest possible score).

```
import itertools

def metric(lst):
    L = len(list(set(lst))) # Number of unique elements
    n = len(list(itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x: x))) # Number of groups
    return n / float(L)   # You can omit float if Python 3

# Test cases
list1 = ['a','a','a','b','b','b']
list2 = ['a','a','b','b','b','a']
list3 = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a']

a = metric(list1)
b = metric(list2)
c = metric(list3)

print(a, b, c)
```

```
1.0 1.5 4.0
```